# Seed a many to many relationship in Prisma

Tags: prisma

I'd like to seed a Prisma DB with a many-to-many relationship

I have a Playlist model, and a Artist model. I'd like to connect artists to their playlist by name, instead of doing it by ID

So, I came up with this:

```
  await prisma.playlist.create({
    data: {
      name: 'Garage Band',
      artists: {
        connectOrCreate: {
          where: {
            name: 'Nirvana',
          },
          create: {
            name: 'Nirvana',
            members: 3,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

But this raises the following error:

```
Type '{ where: { name: string; }; create: { name: string; members: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'PlaylistArtistCreateOrConnectWithoutPlaylistInput | PlaylistArtistCreateOrConnectWithoutPlaylistInput[] | undefined'.
```

It appears that the only usable property is the ID, but since I'd like to connect OR create, I don't have any id yet. Is there a way to simply create the playlist, and connect it to the artists ?